# Threads run in serial not parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to learn concurrency in Java, but whatever I do, 2 threads run in serial, not parallel, so I am not able to replicate common concurrency issues explained in tutorials (like thread interference and memory consistency errors). Sample code:

```
public class Synchronization {
static int v;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Runnable r0 = () -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Synchronization.v++;
            System.out.println(v);
        }
    };

    Runnable r1 = () -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Synchronization.v--;
            System.out.println(v);
        }
    };

    Thread t0 = new Thread(r0);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
    t0.start();
    t1.start();

}
```

}

This always give me a result starting from 1 and ending with 0 (*whatever the loop length is*). For example, the code above gives me every time:

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0

Sometimes, the second thread starts first and the results are the same but negative, so it is still running in serial.

Tried in both Intellij and Eclipse with identical results. CPU has 2 cores if it matters.

UPDATE: it finally became reproducible with huge loops (starting from 1_000_000), though still not every time and just with small amount of final discrepancy. Also seems like making operations in loops "heavier", like printing thread name makes it more reproducible as well. Manually adding sleep to thread also works, but it makes experiment less cleaner, so to say. The reason doesn't seems to be that first loop finishes before the second starts, because I see both loops printing to console while continuing operating and still giving me 0 at the end. The reasons seems more like a thread race for same variable. I will dig deeper into that, thanks.

Comment: Concurrency problems are not "guaranteed" to appear (which is part of what makes them so hard to track and debug. Increase to a few thousand per loop and you might get a problem.

Comment: In addition to what daniu said: I wouldn't be surprised if the loop of `t0` was already finished in the instant the line `t1.start()` is reached.

Comment: Change interations count to 1000000 and say it is serial again.

Comment: On top of that, System.out.println creates a synchronisation point, although you do not see it. This means both your runnables can not actually proceed writing to system.out at the same time, providing some kind of "serial" running on part of your code. You'd probably have a "higher probability" of observing something wrong if you did not println on each iteration, but only at the end.

Comment: Add these two statement inside your loop.
`              System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
  try {
   Thread.sleep(100);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
`
This will add some sleep to the thread and will print the current thread where you can see two running threads.

Comment: 1_000_000 finally makes it reproducible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like first started thread just never give a chance to second in Thread Race to take a variable/second one just never have a time to even start (couldn't say for sure), so the second almost* always will be waiting until first loop will be finished.

Some heavy operation will mix the result:
`TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);`

*it is not always true, but you are was lucky in your tests

Answer (score 1):

Starting a thread is heavyweight operation, meaning that it will take some time to perform. Due that fact, by the time you start second thread, first is finished.

The reasoning why sometimes it is in "revert order" is due how thread scheduler works. By the specs there are not guarantees about thread execution order - having that in mind, we know that it is possible for second thread to run first (and finish)

Increase iteration count to something meaningful like 10000 and see what will happen then.

Comment: maybe 10_000 is still not enough, I would go for 1_000_000 or so

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger nah, IO is expensive as well, so this will do - i think 1k would be enought

Comment: does not on my laptop.... I get non-zero result half the time when using 1_000_000. Did not happen with less

Comment: And you end up with 0 flat ?

Comment: ends with zero  when  using 100_000.(just done a couple of tests, still some real work to do)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger woah cannot reproduce your result on online compilers :(

Comment: lets just agree that 10 is way too small - and multi-threading is hard to reproduce, too many factors and so

Answer (score 1):

This is called lucky timing as per Brian Goetz (Author of Java Concurrency In Practice). Since there is no synchronization to the static variable `v` it is clear that this class is not thread-safe.